# Generate UUID with timestamp method

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform an xml source into several xml output files where the filenames are based on a guid (f.e "97749654-886A-11E6-1885-09173F13E4C5.xml"). 
I am using xslt 2.0 and the home edition of saxon, so I can't use randomUUID().
In other posts I found the workaround with the timestamp method. 
But it seems that the current-dateTime() stays the same in the transformation. So the transformation errors because the guid and thus the filenames stay the same.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Wouldn't a combination of timesamp and the id of the parent node be unique? -- P.S. When referring to a method you have found "in other posts", a link to those posts would be useful.

Comment: Have you seen and tried this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/30775426/6805256? Might be worth a try.

Comment: @uL1 Have *you* tried it?

Comment: Yes i tried it in oxygen and i know it about a long time. Sorry, why do you ask?

Comment: @uL1 Because the link is broken.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the link to question works for me. the link in the answer is broke, but the xslt is posted inline and works as well.

Comment: That's the example I tried (stackoverflow.com/a/30775426/6805256).
Maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but the timestamp part doesn't seem to change when you generate the next id. I added a call template ..
<xsl:variable name="uuidMain">
    <xsl:call-template name="GenGuid"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="GenGuid">
    <xsl:value-of select="uuid:get-uuid()"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--
Functions in the uuid: namespace are used to calculate a UUID
The method used is a derived timestamp method, which is explained
here: http://www.famkruithof.net/guid-uuid-timebased.html

Comment: <xsl:function name="uuid:get-uuid" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:variable name="ts" select="uuid:ts-to-hex(uuid:generate-timestamp())"/>
            <xsl:value-of separator="-" select="
                substring($ts, 8, 8),
                substring($ts, 4, 4),
                string-join((uuid:get-uuid-version(), substring($ts, 1, 3)), ''),
                uuid:generate-clock-id(),

Comment: That is not a problem of you. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387103/xslt-function-returns-different-results-saxon-ee-vs-saxon-he-pe.

Comment: Just add to the UUID something that at that moment in the transformation is different -- without seeing your code it is not good to be more precise in this recommendation. For example, you can use whatever is different in the value of the `href` attribute of the `<xsl:result-document>` instruction.